# Visual Studio Code Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

When I try to run Python code in the terminal with a print command, nothing happens. When I try the `test.py` command in the terminal itself, the text copied below is what gets output.

Please assist in how to get the terminal to print my code.

```
cd E:\Kath\Documents\blockchain
test.py
```

Output:

```
test.py : The term 'test.py' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ test.py
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound:
    (test.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundExce
  ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFound
   Exception
```

Comment: `python test.py` ?

Comment: Thanks! tried this and it output the same message again. any other ideas?

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably?

Answer (score 1):

Once you open the VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), start typing the **Python: Select Interpreter** command to search, then select the command.
You can also use the Select Python Environment option on the Status Bar if available.
Now, create a new file, and save it with the extension **.py**. Once done this, write the required code in the workspace. And then Right Click on the workspace -->Run Python file in the terminal.
This runs the selected file. 
Hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

In "Terminal" you get what is essentially a regular Command prompt, and command interpreter in your case is PowerShell.

So, to execute the python script you should run it as:

```
python test.py
```

or

```
python3 test.py
```

or similar, depending of your python executable.

As Powershell is your default command shell in Visual Studio Code, if the ".py" extension is registered with Python, you can try:

```
.\test.py
```

If you use virtual environments, make sure you select the correct Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I've tried both the options offered and both returned the same output message again. Where do I check the python interpreter?

Comment: Thanks...This is useful, but still hasn't solved my problem. My code still won't run in the terminal, I don't seem to have any options for a python interpreter. Is this something I'm supposed to download?

Comment: Yes. :)  I assumed that you had python already installed. Download the Python installer for Windows from python.org first. Try this link https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Oh yes, I have visual studio code downloaded....it's the connection between where i write the code, and the terminal that I can't get to work

Comment: My previous comment is about installing Python, not visual studio code. Do you jave Python installed? Download from python.org if not.

Comment: Yes, I do have python installed. Should I be coding in that program instead of in visual studio code?

Comment: No, you need Python to run the code and an IDE (vs code) to edit the code. 
Can you try the following:
(a) while the "test.py" is open in vs code, select from menu "Debug -> Start without Debugging"  and report results
(b) in Visual Studio Code, click "Terminal -> New Terminal" and then in terminal window that just opened type "python --version" and post the results here
(c) can you open in VS Code "View -> Command Palette..", then start typing "Python select interpreter", click the item in palette list. The list of available Python interpreters should pop up. Please post the list here.

Comment: When i type "python --version" the following is returned.python : The term 'python' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python --version
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectN
   otFound: (python:String) [], Comm
  andNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Command
   NotFoundException

Comment: It seems that the setup is not OK. I strongly suggest that you reinstall VS Code and follow the tutorial on setting Python development environemnt in details. Try this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: Try running ".\test.py" in terminal, also.