# Visual Studio Code - Difference between results in "Output" console vs "Run in Terminal"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to Visual Studio Code and programming in general. I downloaded VS Code and installed the Python extensions as well as the Code Runner extension. I am following a course on Udemy for new Python programmers...

My issue is when I run the code ( a simple print("Hello World")), I press the play button on the upper right and it gives me the option to "Run Code" or "Run Python File in Terminal". The instructor doesn't have this option appear and he simply presses Run and it shows the result in the OUTPUT console and not the terminal. I have uninstalled and reinstalled it as well as removed the extensions and reinstalled it.

[image: Run Code vs Run in Terminal]

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065221/visual-studio-code-terminal  , also to run project as a vscode task check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125120/visual-studio-code-run-code-in-the-same-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This display is normal. Previously, when we used the "Code Runner" extension, the run button "`Run Code`" provided by it would overwrite the "`Run Python File in Terminal`" button provided by the "Python" extension. But now, these two buttons are integrated, which allows us to choose two different ways of performing the display: in "`OUTPUT`" or "`Terminal`".

"Run Code":

[image]

"Run Python File in Terminal":

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! What is the difference between the too? Any quicker way of running other than having to select which one?

Comment: @bale53 -"Run Code" is output in "OUTPUT" by default, which does not support user input and displays more clearly, while "Run Python File in Terminal" executes code in "Terminal", which supports user interaction. They are different in the way the command is executed.

Comment: I See. Ok Thanks